# How to define multiple routes in single module

Tags: magento2, module

I am defining two routes to be used in same module.

```
<router id="standard">    
    <route frontName="hello" id="hello">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
    <route frontName="blog" id="blog">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

This is not working as expected.

I am expecting it to work like

websitename/hello
websitename/blog

I created Controller folder inside that created Blog and Index folder with Blog.php and Index.php with execute method.

Could you please tell me where is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

let me explain to you how it work. these two `frontName` will go to same controller **Controller/Index/Index.php**

```
<router id="standard">    
    <route frontName="hello" id="hello">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
    <route frontName="blog" id="blog">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

if you want to give them different layout you can do that from 
layout

**frontName** `hello`

```
Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/hello_index_index.xml
```

**frontName** `blog`

```
Namespace/Modulename/view/frontend/layout/blog_index_index.xml
```

by default they will go to same **controller/index/index**.

Comment: Thanks for you are answer @Satti which is very useful for me and it is worked for me.

Comment: @Qaisar, What is the Controller folder structure if we have url like below, /front_name/test-view/index

Comment: Do you mean that we can't  create another controller? One for all?

Comment: @revo it is about using same controller with different layout. It is landing on default frontname/index/index

Comment: How about the original question? How to have two different URLs with the first segment different?

Comment: That is answered. Read answer again

Comment: You're saying the same controller handles both front names. It means one `execute()` method for both. What if I want to apply different logics for each front name? I'm not talking about loading a layout.

Comment: You Can get front name and use your logic accordingly