# M2 - one frontend for one store in routes.xml

Tags: magento2, store-view, websites, routing, router

How can I have multiple route available for one module but different store ? I have one module that is going to be used for several stores (us / de / fr etc..)
I would like to have something like :

`https://mysite/hello_world` for the US store

`https://mysite/bonjour` for the French store

BUT I don't want to have the `hello_world` available for the French store neither the `bonjour` for the US store.

How can I do that ? I already found this : [How to define multiple routes in single module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141618/how-to-define-multiple-routes-in-single-module) So in `routes.xml` I can set multiple frontend route but I can not defined the store. 
So how can I have one frontend for one store in routes.xml ?