# Routing : how to specify a controller and a method for a specific URL?

Tags: magento2, module, routing

How could I give the controller's name (class name) and its method in routes.xml from a plugin ?

for insance, I have two front routes, and I would like them to point to :

> in the file MyCompany/MyModule/Controller/MyPath/Index.php : **method foo()**

and

> in the file MyCompany/MyModule/Controller/MyPath/Index.php : **method bar()**

Here is the routes.xml file

> etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="foo_route" frontName="foo">
            <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" />
        </route>
        <route id="bar_superroute" frontName="bar">
            <module name="MyCompany_MyModule" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

---

**Update :**

I used Qaisar Satti's suggestion :

> in index.php :

```
public function execute() {//InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output) 
{
    $route = $this->getRequest()->getRouteName();
    $this->$route(); //this will call foo_route() or bar_superroute()
}


protected function foo_route() {
    $params = $this->request->getParams();
    //do some awesome things
}

protected function bar_superroute() {
    $params = $this->request->getParams();
    //do some other super awesome bar things
}
```

Comment: IF this is a bad approach to Routing/Controller, please, please, explain to me the proper way. I come from a MVC world, and routing are meant to link an URL to a controller+method .

Answer (score 1):

As far i know there is no direct method. You can get your route name by

`$this->getRequest()->getRouteName();`

Call your require method.

**Or**

You can do it via layout if you want too.
[Solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141618/how-to-define-multiple-routes-in-single-module)

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea: Magento 2 comes from with Test Driven Development and [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). With the SOLID:

> Single responsibility principle
>
> a class should have only a single responsibility (i.e. changes to only
>   one part of the software's specification should be able to affect the
>   specification of the class).

So, I think this is the main reason why one controller class should have only action class.

One more thing, the controller class in Magento 2 is shorter and easier for management purpose in comparison with Magento 1.

Comment: This is a very good quote, and I should have seen it before using the other suggestion.