# Custom Routers for Custom Collection

Tags: magento2, router

I have a custom extension that adds 'testimonials' functionality to M2. The path that I can access these testimonials in the frontend is `/testimonials/index/index`. I've added a `type` field to the testimonials where I can set it to either "reviews" or "customer letters".

What I want to do is create two custom routes in this extension so that I can access in one the "customer reviews" through the `/customer-reviews` path, and in the other the "customer letters" with the `/customer-letters` path.

I've spent the last two days trying to figure this out and haven't been able to get it working.

Can you please guide me through this? I'm a frontend developer trying to do some backend stuff.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this?

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/141625/70343

```
<router id="standard">    
    <route frontName="customer-reviews" id="reviews">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
    <route frontName="customer-letters" id="letters">
        <module name="HelloWorld_Hello"/>
    </route>
</router>
```

So basically have multiple entries in routes.xml