# routes.xml complains about empty tag, which is obviously not empty

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, xml

I have python background so its really hard for me to get my hands on magento2, since I've never touched php/xml/js etc. before.

Currently I just want to add a button in admin backend, which leads to a "export orders" section.

Unfortunately I do not understand, why I get following error inside my `routes.xml` which is located in `vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/`

content of `routes.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="new" frontName="new">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend">
                <router id="admin">
                    <route id="menu" frontName="menu">
                        <module name="Vendor_Module" />
                    </route>
                </router>
            </module>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

As soon as I open the backend it throws following error:
`Element 'module': Character content is not allowed, because the content type is empty. LINE 6`

As you can see its not empty and I already made sure, that vendor_module is always the same like i defined in my `module.xml`

Comment: You have two module elements. One is empty, the other is not. It's complaining about the one that isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> **Please check your file content in the below URL. There is some special character or Unicode in your file that you can not see.**

> > link: https://freetools.textmagic.com/unicode-detector

> **Or you can delete the whole file content and write manually all content in routes.xml.**

Also Check this link : [How to define multiple routes in single module](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141618/how-to-define-multiple-routes-in-single-module)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="new" frontName="new">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
        <route id="menu" frontName="menu">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot nest router/route nodes.
Try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="new" frontName="new">
            <module name="Vendor_Module" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
        <route id="menu" frontName="menu">
            <module name="Vendor_Module"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```